# Rails sort search results by AND comparison and then OR comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, search

Using RoR 3.2, I have a search that searches for comma separated keywords; for example "apple, orange" will find any record that has the word "apple" or the word "orange".  I would like to be able to sort the results so that any records that contain both words are displayed first. For example

A search for "Apple, Orange" would display the record

"Orange slices and apple pie"

before the record

"Apple Juice"

even if Apple Juice is found first.  How can I add this first level sort before sorting by alphanumeric order?  I'm thinking I could do this in the controller index action by setting the order of the index search to first display any records that have "apple" AND "orange", then display all other records that have "apple" OR "orange", I just don't know how to do such a thing.

Here is the scope that searches for a set of comma separated values:

```
scope :by_description, ->(desc=nil) {
if desc.blank?
  all
else
  terms = desc.split(/\s*,\s*/).map { |t| t.strip }.map { |t| "%#{t}%" }
  where( ( ["#{table_name}.description like ?"] * terms.count).join(' or '), *terms )
end
}
```

I call the scope in my controller like so:

```
def index
  order = sortable_column_order
if params[:drawings].blank?
   @drawings = Drawing.paginate page: params[:page], order: order, per_page: 100
else
  @search_string = params[:drawings][:description]
  @drawings = Drawing.by_description(params[:drawings][:description])\
  .by_drawing_number(params[:drawings][:drawing_number])\
  .by_item_number(params[:drawings][:item_number])\
  .by_pump_model(params[:drawings][:pump_model])\
  .by_frame_size(params[:drawings][:frame_size])\
  .by_part_type(params[:drawings][:part_type])\
  .by_created_before(params[:drawings]['created_before(1i)'], params[:drawings]['created_before(2i)'], params[:drawings]['created_before(3i)'])\
  .by_created_after(params[:drawings]['created_after(1i)'], params[:drawings]['created_after(2i)'], params[:drawings]['created_after(3i)'])\
  .paginate page: params[:page], order: order, per_page: 100
  @drawings = @drawings.sort_data(@search_string)

end
```

This is what I'm trying to put together for the sort method but it doesn't work yet, I'm not sure how to correctly pull in the search results and resort them. (I'm using the handles_sortable_columns gem).

```
def sort_data(search_string)
    results_array =
    search_array = search_string.gsub(/\s+/, "").split(",")
    result = []
    results_array.each do |string|
      every_word = true
      one_word = false

      search_array.each do |search|
        if string.downcase.include? search.downcase
            one_word = true
        else
            every_word = false
        end
      end
      if every_word
        result.unshift(string)
      elsif one_word
        result << string
      end
    end
    return result
  end
```

Comment: you are using rails 3.9??? How?

Comment: I'm from the future.  (Haha, oops, I meant 3.2)

Comment: You would like that to happen on sql or ruby space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have a array of input strings to search from and you get the search parameters in another string in a comma separated format. Please find the code below.

```
strings = ["Orange slices and apple pie" , "apple juice", "orange juice", "jackfruit juice", "mixed fruit", "apple pie and orange juice"]
search_string = "apple , orange"
search_array = search_string.gsub(/\s+/, "").split(",")
result = []
strings.each do |string|
    every_word = true
    one_word = false

    search_array.each do |search|
        if string.downcase.include? search.downcase
            one_word = true
        else
            every_word = false
        end
    end
    if every_word
        result.unshift(string)
    elsif one_word
        result << string
    end
end

puts result.inspect
```

**Result**

```
["apple pie and orange juice", "Orange slices and apple pie", "apple juice", "orange juice"]
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: This looks good, now I just need to work on how to get it integrated into my code.  You are right, my search_string is simply in the params, and I just need to reroute my strings array through this sorting function before returning the index.

Comment: Take a look at the code I'm starting with that I added to the original post.  Would I add an additional method in my model to do the sorting, and then just add that to Drawing.by_description(params[:drawings][:description]).NEWMETHOD.all ?

Comment: Yes you could do that. Although I have written the code as it were to be a part of the controller. Although yes, by Rails convention its better to have it in the model. I would recumbent to write a sort_data method which could the above logic.

Comment: Well I'm still working on getting everything to work, but I'm sure once I figure out how all of the methods need to work, this logic will be correct.

Comment: Good luck @sabrams. If you need further clarifications feel free to comment. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I posted my full code above if you're interested in taking a look at all, but I'm sure if I keep playing I'll get it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two different approaches. One in **Ruby** space and one on **SQL** space.

#### Ruby

You can implement a new class that inherits from `String` and messes up with the `<=>` method

```
class FunkyString < String
  def initialize(literal, words = [])
    @words = words
    super(literal)
  end

  def <=>(other)
    if funky_score != other.funky_score
      result = other.funky_score <=> funky_score
    else
      result = super(other)     # fallback to classic string sort
    end
  end

  def funky_score
    @words.map{ |word| self.include?(word) ? 1 : 0 }.inject(:+)
  end
end
```

so for the strings that *Saurabh Lodha* proposed:

```
strings = ["Orange slices and apple pie" , "apple juice", "orange juice", 
           "jackfruit juice", "mixed fruit", "apple pie and orange juice"]

strings.shuffle.map {|s| FunkyString.new(s, ['apple', 'orange']) }.sort

#=> ["apple pie and orange juice", "Orange slices and apple pie", "apple juice",
#    "orange juice", "jackfruit juice", "mixed fruit"]
```

One way to integrate this to your `drawing` model is

```
class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.my_weird_sort(keywords = [])
    sort_by { |record| record.funky_string_field(keywords) }
  end

  def funky_string_field(keywords = [])
    FunkyString.new(string_field, keywords)
  end
end
```

#### SQL

```
select string_field, IF(string_field LIKE '%apple%', 1, 0) + IF(string_field LIKE '%orange%', 1, 0) AS the_score from test_tab order by the_score desc, string_field asc;
```

which results in:

```
+-----------------------------+-----------+
| string_field                | the_score |
+-----------------------------+-----------+
| apple pie and orange juice  |         2 |
| Orange slices and apple pie |         2 |
| apple juice                 |         1 |
| orange juice                |         1 |
| jackfruit juice             |         0 |
| mixed fruit                 |         0 |
+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

so that can be transferred to a rails scope as follows:

```
scope :weird_order ->(word_1, word_2) { 
  select("select string_field, IF(string_field LIKE '%?%', 1, 0) + IF(string_field LIKE '%?%', 1, 0) AS the_score", word_1, word_2).
  order("he_score desc, string_field asc")
}
```

so you'll have

```
@drawings.weird_order("apple", "orange")
```

*********  **UPDATE** ****************

For an arbitrary number of elements in the sql approach you can construct the query string:

select string_field, IF(string_field LIKE '%apple%', 1, 0) + IF(string_field LIKE 
'%orange%', 1, 0) AS the_score from test_tab order by the_score desc, string_field asc;

```
q = "select string_field, "
q += keywords.map{|x| "IF(string_field LIKE '%" + x + "%', 1, 0)"}.join(" + ")
q += AS the_score from test_tab order by the_score desc, string_field asc"
```

and then execute the custom query. Keep in mind that if you follow that you'll need to check for sql injections!

Comment: What if there are an unknown number of words to search for?  The user could enter "apple", "apple, orange", "apple, orange, juice", and so on for as many as they'd like.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I just don't quite follow the code (I'm very new to programming and ruby :/ )